# Change number of items for mobile in caroufredsel

Tags: jquery, carousel, caroufredsel

I'm trying to change the number of items that Caroufredsel shows on mobile. Right now I have it set for to show 4 items and scroll 4 at a time on desktop. For mobile I want it to only show 2 items and scroll through 2 at a time. Is that possible?

```
$('#multimedia').carouFredSel({
        width: "980px",
        height: "auto",
        prev: "#prev",
        next: "#next",
        auto: false,
        responsive: true,
        items: 4,
        auto: {
            play: false
        },
        pagination: "#pagination",
        scroll: {   
            items: 4,
            easing : "swing"
        }                 
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

Yep, totally possible, hopefully you can take something from my config file:

```
        responsive : true,
        height : "auto",
        items:
        {
            width: 551,
            visible:
                {
                    min: 1,
                    max: 3
                }
        },
        scroll : {
            items:
            {
                width: 900,
                visible:
                    {
                        min: 1,
                        max: 3
                    }
            },
            easing          : "quadratic",
            duration        : 700
        },
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me 

     {
        responsive: true,
        circular: true,
        infinite: true,
        items: {
            visible: {
                min: 1,
                max: 6
            },
            width: 100,
            height: '150%'
        },
        scroll: {
            items: {
                visible: {
                    min: 1,
                    max: 6
                },
                width: 100
            }
        }}

Comment: OK, it was a matter of to small width for item